# Programmatically getting all analyzers from ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Is there an elegant way to get all analyzers of ElasticSearch 5.3 or 5.4 programmatically?
I have used some Java code with the Java driver for 5.3, but this is not a clean solution:

```
public Map<String, AnalyzerProvider<?>> extractAllIndices() throws IOException {
    Settings settings = Settings.builder()
            .put(Environment.PATH_HOME_SETTING.getKey(), System.getProperty("user.home"))
            .put(IndexMetaData.SETTING_VERSION_CREATED, 1)
            .put(IndexMetaData.SETTING_VERSION_CREATED_STRING, "1")
            .put(IndexMetaData.SETTING_NUMBER_OF_SHARDS, 1)
            .put(IndexMetaData.SETTING_NUMBER_OF_REPLICAS, 1)
            .build();
    Environment environment = new Environment(settings);
    AnalysisModule module = new AnalysisModule(environment, Collections.emptyList());
    IndexSettings indexSettings = new IndexSettings(new IndexMetaData.Builder("test")
            .settings(settings)
            .build(),
            settings);
    return module.getAnalysisRegistry().buildAnalyzerFactories(indexSettings);
}
```

This code retrieves all analyzers used internally by the driver. But this is rather a hack.

These are all analyzers I could find with the 5.3 driver using the code above:

```
standard
german
pattern
irish
sorani
simple
standard_html_strip
hungarian
norwegian
dutch
chinese
default
arabic
english
fingerprint
portuguese
keyword
romanian
french
czech
greek
indonesian
swedish
spanish
danish
russian
cjk
armenian
basque
italian
lithuanian
thai
persian
catalan
finnish
classic
stop
brazilian
turkish
hindi
snowball
bulgarian
whitespace
galician
latvian
```

Comment: `GET /_all/_settings`  is maybe what you're looking for. It will get a JSON payload of all settings across all indexes (which includes analyzers). This appears to be the equivalent java API to do that: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-admin-indices.html#java-admin-indices-get-settings.

Comment: @Kevin thank you. I did not know about that query (`GET /_all/_settings`). I have tried it out, but it just displayed the settings for all indices. Yet this does not give me the full list of analyzers in ElasticSearch. It is quite convenient for getting all settings though.

Comment: Do you want all possible analyzers or the ones actually used by the indexes? Settings will show you any custom analyzers for your indexes which is what i thought you were looking for

Comment: @Kevin I want all possible analyzers, not just the ones used by the indexes.